# metismenu.js file not loading (No route matches [GET] "/users/jquery.metisMenu.js") in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I get the following error in my console when it tries to load the assets:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/jquery.metisMenu.js")
```

I have this in application.html.erb file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
```

Why does the navigation try to look for /users/jquery... Why does it look under the users folder?  I tried to do assets/jquery... but that doesn't seem to work either as metisMenu.js isn't within my directory structure.

I followed this: https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't have a leading `/` in the src value, it appends the src to the current url.  If it was in your public folder somewhere you would do

```
<script src="/<path from public to parent folder>/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
```

Since you say it's not in your directory structure i assume you're loading it from an external source, in which case you'll need to url to the file, like you do with jquery.min.js

EDIT - looking at the github page, what i would do if i wanted to use this would be the following (in the terminal, from my project root)

```
cd public/javascripts
git clone https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu.git
```

then in my view

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
```

Comment: BTW, looking at that page, it looks they they expect you to download it into your project (somewhere in public), and then reference it like in my answer.  I think their example link to it is going to not work for most people.

Comment: It worked! Now that I think about it, it was pretty obvious what I had to do.  One question, why put this in public directory?  Can't I just put it in the app/assets directory?

Comment: Other question...how do I get it to work on Heroku? It seems that it isn't picking up this metismenu.js file

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about how rails works now (i'm on an older version).  In development you can read out of the app/assets directory but for production the files in here are "precompiled" into the public folder.  It sounds like you just need to do this precompile step.  Have a look at `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html`